# How to setup multi-operator dag so that another instance would not get instantiated until all tasks of the running instance are completed?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We have multi-operator dags in our airflow implementation.
Lets say dag-a has operator t1, t2, t3 which are set up to run sequentially (ie.  t2 is dependent on t1, and t3 is dependent on t2.)

```
 task_2.set_upstream(task_1)
 task_3.set_upstream(task_2)
```

We need to insure that when dag-a is instantiated, all its tasks complete successfully before another instance of the same dag is instantiated (or before the first task on the next dag instance is triggered.)

we have set the following in our dags:

```
da['depends_on_past'] = True
```

What is happening right now is that if the instantiated dag does not have any errors, we see the desired effect.
However, lets say dag-a is scheduled to run hourly. On the hour dag-a-i1 instance is trigged as scheduled.  Then dag-a-i1 task t1 runs successfully and then t2 starts running and fails.  In that scenario , we see dag-a-i1 instance stops as expected.  when the next hour comes, we see dag-a-i2 instance is triggered and we see task t1 for that dag instance (i2) starts running and lets say completes, and then the dag-a-i2 stops, since its t2 can not run because previous instanse of t2 (for dag-a-i1) has failed status.

The behavior we need to see is that the second instance not get triggered, or if it gets triggered, we do not want to see task t1 for that second instance get triggered. This is causing problem for us.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Before I begin to answer, I'm going to set up lay out a naming conventions that will differ from the one you presented in your question.

`DagA.TimeA.T1` will refer to an instance of a DAG `A` executing task `T1` at time `A`.

Moving on, I see two potential solutions here.

**The first:**

Although not particularly pretty, you could add a sensor task to the beginning of your DAG. This sensor should wait for the execution of the final task of the same DAG. Something like the following should work:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.sensors import ExternalTaskSensor
from datetime import timedelta

dag = DAG(dag_id="ETL", schedule_interval="@hourly")
ensure_prior_success = ExternalTaskSensor(external_dag_id="ETL", 
external_task_id="final_task", execution_delta=timedelta(hours=1))
final_task = DummyOperator(task_id="final_task", dag=dag)
```

Written this way, if any of the non-sensor tasks fail during a `DagA.TimeA` run, `DagA.TimeB` will begin executing its sensor task but will eventually timeout.

If you choose to write your DAG in this way, there are a couple things you should be aware of.

1. If you are planning on performing backfills of this DAG (or, if you think you ever may), you should set your DAG's `max_active_runs` to a low number. The reason for this is that a large enough backfill could fill the global task queue with sensor tasks and create a situation where new tasks are be unable to be queued.
2. The first run of this DAG will require human intervention. The human will need to mark the initial sensor task as success (because no previous runs exist, the sensor cannot complete successfully).

**The second:**

I'm not sure what work your tasks are performing, but for sake of example let's say they involve writes to a database. Create an operator that looks at your database for evidence that `DagA.TimeA.T3` completed successfully.

As I said, without knowing what your tasks are doing, it is tough to offer concrete advice on what this operator would look like. If your use-case involves a constant number of database writes, you could perform a query to count the number of documents that exist in the target table `WHERE TIME <= NOW - 1 HOUR`.